# Stanford CoreNLP - dashes

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am experiencing a problem with the use of the Stanford pipeline (last version of CoreNLP) to parse the BNC.

The problematic sentence excerpt is the following, and the problem are the dashes (if I remove them, it goes through).

"... they did it again and again — on and off for years."

The parser just gets stuck in this sentence, and it does not even throw an error.The sentence gets parsed correctly in the web interface.

I tried with the options of the tokenizer, with no result.

I add the command line I am using: 
java [...] edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse -tokenize.whitespace false -ssplit.eolonly true -parse.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_SD.gz -file $inputfile

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to cope with this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Gabriella

Answer (score 1):

Running with Stanford CoreNLP v.3.5.2 on OS X 10.10.4, I couldn't reproduce this problem. The example string given was parsed just fine.

There could be a problem, but if so it is subtle and you'd want to similarly give more information on Stanford NLP version, OS and version, and to stick a textfile that doesn't work somewhere to be downloaded, to make sure the problem isn't something like line endings that gets lost when pasting text on a web page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking care of my question!

Comment: I am using Stanford Corenlp-3.5.2, on a computer cluster whose nodes have Linux  3.0.101-0.47.50. The problematic sentence is in fact longer than what I originally posted: as I wrongly assumed the problem was in the dashes, I cut it my original post. Sorry for that!  I have uploaded the corresponding .txt file at the following link: http://cogsci.uni-osnabrueck.de/~glapesa/problematic_sentence.txt

Comment: The full sentence also processes okay on my Mac.... What version of Java are you running? Oracle Java 8 (what build?) or a version of OpenJDK that comes with Linux?

Comment: I am running jdk 1.8.0_45 for Linux. A colleague on mine pointed out the issue could be related to the parser model, and I found out that the sentence goes through with other parser models: englishPCFG, englishRNN, SR, SR.beam.

Comment: Just a little update on the issue. The problem concerns Universal Dependencies only. The thread does not hang if I properly load the Stanford Dependencies model (namely with "depparse" in the annotators, and -depparse.model - this was the mistake in the command line I posted, where I have "depparse" in the annotators and -parse.model in the call to the model... as I used to do in the 2015-01-29 version).

Comment: I never got back to this, but I still can't reproduce this problem. I can run on this sentence with either version 3.5.2 or 3.6.0 using either UD or SD dependencies and it runs to completion without problem. (BTW to specify the depparse model you need to use `-depparse.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz` - I assume you are doing that.) If a job is hanging, you should try to generate a stack trace, either with `CTRL-\` or the `jstack` command.... That would help greatly to track things down.